# decrypting a dvd and testing that it is decrypted and playing it locally with its menu?

Tags: windows, dvd, mplayer, decryption

I have a DVD , it may be decrypted. How do I get it to hard drive decrypt it and see if it is decrypted?

I have got it to hard drive... I can get VOB files to play(does that mean it is not encrypted?) but I can't get it to play with the menu.

I can get the DVD itself to play with a menu.

I'd like to get the local copy to.

Also, I can play the first VOB file in VLC and MPC but not in mplayer. But that's a secondary thing.

I will use whatever player you suggest.  I have tried VLC, and mplayer, and media player classic.

Comment: In my experience, once a dvd is ripped to vob files it's "decrypted".

Comment: If D is the DVD drive and you browse D:\ on an encrypted DVD, what do you see?

Comment: How did you get it to the hard drive?, what software did you use? Most DVD ripping software decrypts the VOB files when copying them to the hard drive.

Comment: @Moab I can see the VOB files on the DVD so I guess they were not decrypted even on the DVD. I used DVD smith, and I used(to another destination directory), claddvd. Does that make any difference to you? BTW. What would a DVD look like if you do DIR on it or Explore it, and it is encrypted?

Comment: VOB files can be encrypted or unencrypted, you cannot tell by looking at them on a DVD. Most commercial DVDs are encrypted.,,see this link...http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/662150

Comment: @Moab  Is copy protection and DVD encryption the same thing?

Comment: Not really, encryption was an attempt to keep you from simply  copying the files from the DVD to another source like a hard drive, similar to what they did for CDs, but they figured out how to "rip" the files off of the CD/DVD, Copy protection is just that, an attempt to prevent you from copying the disc to another disc, or in other words, duplicating it.